# std::condition_variable notify_all not waking up all threads at the same time

Tags: windows, multithreading, c++11, threadpool, condition-variable

What I'd like to know is how does std::condition_variable notify_all work as far as notifying all threads to wake.

The situation is that I have a main thread, a render thread, and each of those has its own thread pool to do whatever work it needs to.  For example, if I have 6 logical cores, each thread pool would have 6 worker threads.  These threads are woken using notify_all.   Each thread pool has its own condition variable/mutex combo and are totally separate, so they do not conflict with each other.

The issue I'm having is that at times, when the render thread calls notify_all to wake up the worker threads, some will be woken immediately and some will take a long time, in the order of multiple milliseconds.

I have also noticed that this mostly happens when these threads are woken while the main thread workers are busy doing work of their own.  So, at times of heavy load when there's already a thread per logical core working, trying to wake up these other threads exhibits this behavior.  So out of the 6 threads that are waiting for the condition_variable, maybe 4 will be woken up, and the other two will not be until the load goes down.

My question is, is this expected behavior, or should I be looking to a bug in my code?  Note, the threads always wake up, and under no load or light load, they usually wake up at around the same time.  I also have no deadlocks or any other problems with my thread pool setup.   So, am I just seeing the correct behavior of condition_variable where some threads can be woken quickly and others 4 or 5 ms later?  How can I mitigate this behavior?  Can anyone suggest an alternate way to wake up my worker threads that might work best?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

They cannot be woken up until they get scheduled. If other threads are running they get to complete their time-slice first.

How else would this work?

Comment: Ok, so perhaps I've been understanding how the scheduler deals with all these threads incorrectly.  I thought that it could stop some to give time to others, to try to balance the load?  Are you saying that once a thread is going it cannot be stopped until it yields or some synchronization happens?

Comment: @Owens Once the OS starts a thread it gets to run its time-slice. Then it will be interrupted and the OS will schedule again.

Comment: Right, this is my general impression.  I just thought that a time slice would be a much shorter amount of time.  What I'm seeing is some of these threads waiting 4 or 5 milliseconds, basically until the other running threads completely go to sleep waiting on their synchronization.  And, mind you that while those threads are executing their jobs, after each job there's a yield, specifically to allow other threads to have their chance to run.  So I'm confused here because I'm expecting at the very least for one of those yields to allow the condition_variable to wake these threads.

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684259(v=vs.85).aspx Since slices are 20ms 5ms is actually quite good.

Comment: For some reason I was thinking Windows. Other OS do different things.

Comment: Yes, this is on Windows.  Ok, good to know that time slices can be that large.  I had no idea.  I'm still confused as to why the yields in my update thread pool jobs are not giving these other threads to at least start up, but this gives me more knowledge that I can use to profile this code.

Comment: Also, yield is almost always useless. Don't rely on it.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why yields are useless?  I've been operating under the impression that they would allow other threads to get some time in in between job processing.  If this is incorrect, it would definitely explain the behavior I'm seeing.  Should I do a sleep(0) or something like that?  What can you recommend?

Comment: Yield only yields to a thread waiting on that core. If you're yielding on core 2 and core 8 has three threads waiting it won't steal one. It just goes back to running your thread on core 2.

Comment: Keep your total number of high CPU threads less or equal to the number of cores.

Comment: Ok, interesting.  Yeah basically right now I have my update pool threads which are the ones doing most of the heavy lifting.  Those are the same number as the number of logical cores.  The render worker threads (also the same number as cores) are not doing as much, but if even one stalls waiting to be woken, then the entire render takes much longer.  I've also seen the update workers inexplicably also take much longer, in conjunction with the render ones also doing so.  I'll need to look at this more carefully and see how I can keep everything flowing better.